# How are "might" and "may" used in the past?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, modal-verbs, modality

OK, we all know that *epistemic modals* such as **may** and **might** can be interchanged to express possibility in present & future

For example: *he might be late*, and *he may be late* are almost the same. [Source](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/modal-verbs-of-probability.html)

But **might** is also the past form of **may** in indirect speech:

For example: *He said **he might be late*** = *He said "**I may be late***"

I had some feeling that people lived 100 or 200 or 300 years ago may have used **may** and **might** differently from what we are using nowadays.

I would guess, in the past, ‘*he might be late*’ means ‘*it was possible that he is late*’ and  ‘*he may be late*’ means ‘*it is possible that he is late*’ The word *might* expresses *it **was** possible* and *may* expresses *it **is** possible*, but I may be wrong.

---

I found this information in [this book "Grammatical Change in English World-Wide"](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=QPuADQAAQBAJ&pg=PA221&dq=May%20and%20might%20%22Grammatical%20Change%20in%20English%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9m7_hjO_XAhUKzLwKHU8lCGIQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=May%20and%20might%20%22Grammatical%20Change%20in%20English%22&f=false)

[image]

The book says:

"**something might happen**" in the past (maybe 1000 or 200 or longer time ago) (might + inf) is equivalent to "**something might / may have happened**" (might / may + have +PP) in Modern English.

**Q:** So, how were *might* and *may* used in the past?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: The answer to what I see as the "original" ends with *in modern English, "might" has lost its sense as a past tense*, with the clear implication that it *was* routinely used as a past tense in the past. But although that "specifically *past* tense" sense is still there in contexts like *I **thought** he **might** be insulting me* (where we wouldn't use ***may***), it doesn't apply with *I **think** he might/may be insulting me*, where both versions are effectively equivalent to me.

Comment: ***May and might in nineteenth century Irish English and English English*** https://benjamins.com/catalog/scl.67.10hat

Comment: @Mari-LouA, it seems that, in modern English, we can only use "**might + inf**" in Conditional Type 2 & In reported speech, right? If we want to express past possibility, we have to use "**might have PP**" right?

Comment: You can also use "could" as in: "He could have arrived on time if he had woken earlier" But this has nothing to do with how "may" and "might" ***might have been used*** in the 17th, 18th or 19th century, so I don't really understand why you are asking.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Yes, Modals existed in Old English era. It is wrong to say "**He might be late yesterday**" in Modern English, we have to use "**He might have been late**" instead. But in the past, they used "**He might be late yesterday**"

Answer (score 1):

"Might" was used somewhat more expansively in older English, as you can see from this search of the phrase "might have" in the King James Version of the Bible, first published in the year 1611:

[https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=%22might+have%22&t=KJV#s=s_primary_0_1](https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=%22might%20have%22&t=KJV#s=s_primary_0_1)