# What is the structure of “might did”?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, modal-verbs, multiple-modals

What is the structure of **might + verb (in past tense)** called?

**I might said it.** (Instead of *I might have said it.*)

**I might did it.** (Instead of *I might have done it.*)

**I might did say it.** (Instead of *I might have said it.*, with **did** as an auxiliary verb.)

The verbs **said** and **did** are not *modal*, and so these examples are not **double modal**. But I don’t know whether these are speech errors, and I myself *might have said* it (and it might not sound entirely unnatural). **What is this structure?**

I thought it would be nice to have a *name* to the structure when people discuss this type of construction, unlesse it’s **No English** at all but a form of (non)standard **dialect**.

### Prior to this posting, I came across an article, titled *[might didn’t](http://linguistlessons.blogspot.com/2010/11/might-didnt.html?m=1)*, about a similar structure of double modals. I was in hope of making a valid question for the Forum.

This type of structure is not listed in commonly available references, while it is also difficult for lay people to ascertain the facts that its usage is common in particular dialects.

I don’t think the study of its usage is particularly useful for English learners. Learners may get a wrong idea that English speakers in general are receptive to nonstandard usages.

Comment: It's pretty much nonstandard English. "He might did want" in place of "He might have wanted" (standard) or "He might've wanted"

Comment: @Mari-Lou “He might did want” is double modal but I don’t find any examples of “might + modal do” in dictionaries and grammar books. Do you mean that “He might did want” is acceptable while “He might did” isn’t?

Comment: No, it's nonstandard English, a dialect with which I am very unfamiliar.

Comment: @Mari-Lou So you say both “might + verb (past)” and “might + modal (or auxiliary) do” are a “nonstandard dialect” but “standard dialect”?

Comment: In most cases the "have" is there in spirit, it's just been swallowed.  First "might 'ov", next "might've", then "might'a", until eventually "have" is gone entirely, or only present as a slight change in tone or pace.  And in your second example you have a "done" -> "did" exchange which is not uncommon in "illiterate" speech.

Comment: @Hot Licks A very interesting comment! One answer suggests that it’s either a form of black dialect or white Carolinian dialect. Would you call the structure a derivative of illiterate speech?

Comment: Is this something you've actually heard said?

Comment: @1006a Yes, please note that I live in New York City where many different kinds of speech can be heard said. The examples also include the kinds of “I might was gonna (+ verb)”. All of these, some people may say, don’t sound quite unnatural (not me, though). I would like to have them classified either as ungrammatical (thus no English at all) or nonstandard (while they’re existing forms of English speech).

Comment: @wordsalad - I use "illiterate" here to mean "unschooled" -- the individual was raised by similarly-illiterate individuals and did not attend enough school (or pay enough attention) to absorb "proper" syntax.  You can't really connect it with a specific dialect.

Comment: @Hot Licks Quite understood.

Comment: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00335635309381881?journalCode=rqjs20 Perhaps abbreviated speech patterns are a result of hurried lifestyles or even impatience (itself often precipitated by a sense of urgency)?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included information about context in your question. That can help guide folks' research, or possibly trigger someone's "a-ha" moment. It also makes it clearer that you aren't talking about a hypothetical structure, or something that may have been said/written by a non-native speaker. You don't need to say "Edit", just add it in.

Comment: related, perhaps - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420852/how-were-might-and-may-used-in-the-past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In standard English, *might + verb (past)*  is ungrammatical. (If you think you're hearing this, it's probably "might've" you're hearing not just "might".)

For some native speakers (not me though), *might did* may be acceptable. Some studies have recorded a very small handful of hits for *might did* (and similar):

> Table 4 includes five combinations of *may/might/must* with *did*, three of which are given in (10)-(12) below. This type of construction is not [a multiple modal], but it provides important information on the possible grammatical status of the initial modal in combinations. It is attested elsewhere in the literature only in Labov et al. (1968, 262), who claim that it is evidence of a type of do-support distinctive to Black Vernacular English in New York City and that the modal thus functions as an adverb. Di Paolo reports complete rejection of sentences like *She still might don't like it* for her 62 white speakers in Texas (nor did she observe any examples of *might don't* in her years of collecting data: Di Paolo, letter to the authors).
>
> However, all examples in our corpus come from white South Carolinians, raising considerable doubt about the claim of Labov et al. that the initial modal has achieved adverbial status in Black English but not in  Southern White English. Whereas our corpus from the Carolinas has five combinations of *may, might*, and *must* with did, it lacks any with do like those cited in New York City. Butters (1991, 173) notes that "*must/might + do + neg*. could be viewed as an early instance of linguistic divergence of [Black English Vernacular] in New York City," but, citing the occurrence of such forms in Gullah (as reported in Cunningham 1970, 84), he asserts that this is certainly open to question (see also Butters 1989, 101-03).
>
> 10. There weren't no way to be sure; could be he MAY DIDN'T want to come.
> 11. You MIGHT DID already do that.
> 12. We waited as long as we could cause we thought he MIGHT DID want to go with us.
>
> <sub>[The Pragmatics of Multiple Modal Variation in North and South Carolina](http://www.jstor.org.ezaccess.libraries.psu.edu/stable/pdf/455947.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Ae02e22e52a186fd4b1f5a6dff58b2c75)</sub>

Comment: Good answer! Thank you. I’m not black but I’ve only lived in New York, and lived for the most of my life, in New York City, where I hear all sorts of native speakers speak their dialects. Calling it “the modal in adverbial function (or state)” makes sense to me, but I wonder if this construction is commonly accepted.